# Is it possible to just launch the SMS/iMessages (without a compose new message modal view app) from within your own App?

Tags: ios, sms, message

I know that you are able to launch a system app such as the SMS app with a system URL handler in this fashion:

`NSString *stringURL = @"sms:";`

`NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];`

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];`

However, when you launch the SMS/iMessages App in this fashion you are automatically presented with a "compose new message" modal view. Is it possible to just have the SMS app launched in it's regular fashion (a UITableView of your conversations with people) or better yet straight into the view(conversation) that entered the foreground when you previously quit the SMS app?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that MFMessageComposeViewController of MessageUI framework will do it for you:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MessageUI_Framework_Reference/_index.html

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. I thought you were looking for how to programmatically present user UI for sending text message. Your question is how to leave your app and pull up conversation in Messages app. Can't help you there.

Comment: It's ok. Thanks for trying to help.